# Decode JSON data before sending in API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created an API for a DB table. There is a field of 'day' which saves day in json formate like

```
{"week1":["day1", "day2"], "week2":["day1", "day2"]} ({"1": ["3", "4"], "2": ["1", "2", "3"]})
```

Everything's working fine but I checked API on Postman, day is showing like this:

```
"day": "{\"1\": [\"3\", \"4\"], \"2\": [\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]}"
```

when I checked Django admin, data is saving correctly in DB. Does any know how can I send decoded JSON data for this field?

Here is my code:

**serializer.py**

```
class PlanToPackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlanAllocationPackage
        fields = ('plan', 'day')
        depth = 1


class PackageListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    package_name = PlanToPackageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**views.py**

```
class AllPackageView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        package = Package.objects.all()
        serializer = PackageListSerializer(package, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

models.py

```
class PlanAllocationPackage(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, null=True, related_name='plan_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, null=True, related_name='package_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you show you Package model?

Comment: @NicoGriffioen, models.py added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you could use something like get_day on your serialiser like this:

```
class PlanToPackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlanAllocationPackage
        fields = ('plan', 'day')
        depth = 1

    def get_day(self):
        return json.loads(self.day)
```

But I would advise you to use something like a JSONField, which automatically enables you to convert dictionaries to and from JSON.

Also, by setting the max_length of you CharField to 100, you'll run into trouble when you try to save JSON strings that are longer than 100 characters.

Comment: thanx, I used JSONField.